# php captcha using jquery ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, captcha

i have included a captcha functionality to my wordpress site using this plugin: https://github.com/claviska/simple-php-captcha

however i am having difficulities validating the form data and captcha using ajax.

i using `.submit()` to make an ajax post request which sends all the form data to a php file.

however the problem i am facing is that the captcha code keeps changing and therefore my validation will always result to invalid.

this code is placed at the top of `single.php`:

```
session_start();
require_once('library/includes/plugins/simple_php_captcha/index.php');
$_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();
```

this code is placed further down `single.php`:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src'];?>" alt="captcha"/>
```

this code is placed in `ajax-submit.php`

```
session_start();
if($_POST){
    echo "<pre>";
    echo print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo $_SESSION['captcha']['code'];
}
```

this is the `.submit()`

```
$("form").submit(function () {

   var input_captcha = $("#input_captcha").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax-submit.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: "input_captcha="+input_captcha,
            //dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });

        return false;

    });
```

where am i doing/going wrong??

Comment: Try this one useful for you...
http://www.sitepoint.com/setup-user-friendly-captcha-jqueryphp/

Comment: you really should use reCaptcha instead. Writing your own captcha-validation is error-prone and WILL be circumvented at some point.

Comment: using recaptcha will require me to create an account and has styling which will not look appealing on my site. i am trying to achieve this in minimum steps.